# How to unthrottle lambda function where button was clicked to throttle

Tags: aws-lambda

I decided to click on the throttle button on the aws lambda interface in order to prevent further activation of the function while debugging an issue in the process. I see no way to now remove the throttle.

How do I go about removing the throttle now that I clicked on the throttle button?

Regards
Conteh

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I noticed that scrolling down to concurrency on the on the configuration tab. The reserve concurrency was set to 0. Adjusting this to a positive number removes the throttle.

Comment: FYI, the default is to use "Unreserved account capacity" vs that positive number in "Reserved Concurrency".